# How to compute a signature of a matrix

Tags: algorithms

We know some signature/checksum methods for text, like md5,sha.

Now, I want to compute a checksum for a matrix, to represent the exact matrix. Say, two matrixes with different sizes, or with different values, have different checksum. And slightly different matrixes(same size) result in slightly different checksum. So, both layout and values should be considered.

Although the most intuitive method is  to compare two matrixes directly, however, sometimes it's inconvenient to get the two matrixes in the same environment.

Maybe I should check the md5 algorithm, and adapt a similar method. Just post it here for better advices.

Comment: MD5 and SHA aren't defined over text but over byte streams.

Comment: SO has a related or similar discussion on [hashing a matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934827/hash-function-to-matrix) from a while ago that might be helpful.

Comment: This is not a checksum. Good checksum algorithms in fact have the property that even the smallest possible change will result in a different result.

Answer (score 1):

Of the top of my head, it should be fine to convert the martix to a string representation and then do an MD5 of that. The string representation of two matrices with identical dimensions and identical entries would be identical.

For example, despite having identical objects when converted to a single dimension, these two matrices have different string representations.

```
"[[1,2],[3,4]]" != "[1,2,3,4]"
```

However you approach this, you'll need to compare dimentionality and contents.